# Pointers and arrays without using index

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have been asked to sum up an int array and return the sum not using index.
(function needs to get the array and the size)

I know I should've set a pointer to the array and compare the pointer to the array address and use pointer++ to run over the array.

Tho, I wrote down the following code :

```
int sumArray(int nNumArray[], int nSize)
{
    int nSum = 0;

    while(*nNumArray <= &nNumArray[nSize-1])
    {
        nSum += *nNumArray;
        nNumArray++;
    }
    return nSum;
}
```

which works perfectly,

thing is *nNumArray is referring to values and &nNumArray[nSize-1] is referring to an address.

I'm trying to understand how come this way works.

Will appreciate some insights. Thanks.

Comment: Comparing an integer with a pointer -> `(*nNumArray <= &nNumArray[nSize-1])`. This is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

"which works perfectly" : this is impossible

`(*nNumArray <= &nNumArray[nSize-1])` : you compare an *int* into the vector (and later outside it) and an address of an *int* into the vector ( and in fact after its end). A priori your compiler signal the error

Furthermore `&nNumArray[nSize-1]` will not be the end of the vector after the first loop because you modify *nNumArray*

If you want to use a pointer you can use an other variable to store it to not modify *nNumArray*, and to change test like `(ptr <= &nNumArray[nSize-1])` :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumArray(int nNumArray[], int nSize)
{
    int nSum = 0;
    int * ptr = nNumArray;

    while(ptr <= &nNumArray[nSize-1])
    {
        nSum += *ptr++;
    }
    return nSum;
}

int main()
{
  int a[3] = {1,2,3};

  printf("%d\n", sumArray(a, 3));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop condition is incorrect:

```
while(*nNumArray <= &nNumArray[nSize-1])
```

because you are comparing an integer `(*nNumArray)` with a pointer `(&nNumArray[nSize-1])`. Compiler must be giving warning message on this statement.

Instead, you can do:

```
int sumArray(int nNumArray[], int nSize)
{
    int nSum = 0;

    while(nSize--)
    {
        nSum += *nNumArray;
        nNumArray++;
    }
    return nSum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First error** here :

`(*nNumArray <= &nNumArray[nSize-1])`

The name of the array variable itself is considered as a pointer in C, thus `*nNumArray` represents the reference of an pointer.

It should be `nNumArray` to make it compare the address.

**Second error** :

It won't work perfectly if only the first error is fixed.

The index operation works like this :

`&nNumArray[nSize-1]` works the same as `nNumArray + nSize - 1`

Thus the while loop might looks like this :

```
while(nNumArray <= nNumArray + nSize - 1){
    nSum += *nNumArray;
    nNumArray++;
}
```

(This might makes it more simple to see where is wrong)

The while loop will run forever until `*nNumArray` accessed an *int* which is out of the array that causes a segmentation fault.

You might want to do it by using another pointer to compare with `nNumArray + nSize - 1`, and the whole `sumArray` function should look like this:

```
int sumArray(int nNumArray[], int nSize)
{
    int nSum = 0;
    int *ptr = nNumArray;
    while(ptr <= nNumArray + nSize - 1)
    {
        nSum += *ptr;
        ptr++;
    }
    return nSum;
}
```

And now it should work perfectly :)

Comment: Compiler doesn't show any errors to my code, and running it gives the result expected in every situation I tried.
However, I can't understand why it is working, 
If I change the code according to what your said, (the way I wrote it down at first) the code did not work properly.

Comment: I've tried to run your code, but I got a warning about comparison between integer and pointer, I can't understand why it is working on your computer, maybe someone else can help you further. And I revised some expression mistake about the compiler and made a little edit about my code, hope you can understand it more better.